# iOS - Swift 4 - Constraints for text fields side by side

Tags: ios, swift

I Have a view like so:

[image]

And I am trying to add constraints so the text fields are side by side so the auto looks the same no matter the device width, how would I do that?

I have tried the following for all 6 of them:

[image]

But it ends up looking like this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ctrl drag from the description TextField to vendor TextField  and select `Equal Widths` from popup

You can also use a vertical stackView where each row is a horizontal 1  with distribution set to `Equal spacing` and drag the text fields to it that will be more easier

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's look at what we know about the horizontal axis (I assume you've got the vertical axis taken care of). There are two text fields; call them Left and Right. We know these things:

- Where Left's leading edge must be
- Where Right's trailing edge must be
- The distance between Left's trailing and edge and Right's leading edge
- The relationship between Left's width and Right's width, i.e. they are equal

Ta-daa:

[image]

(A UIStackView would construct these same constraints for you, but in a simple situation like this it's probably more trouble than it's worth.)

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do it

I give you two but recommend the first one in your case.

First :

Define a constraint by draging one of your UITextFiled to the other one and set it to  “Equal Widths”

You may also be able to define a percentage for each (60-40%) if you like.

Second :

Define a constraint like above (draging) And define a relative ratio (0.5) for UITextField width against its superview. Do it for the other one. You need to go to Object Inspector Tab and change the values if needed (so this requires two constraints, one for each `UITextField` as each of them are relative to the their superview) this is also a little bit slower than the first approach since margins should be defined with priority.